# Please Help installing Qt centos 7

Tags: linux, installation, centos, python, qt

I have 2 python versions, python3.6 is installed on virtualenv for development use, I am trying to install PyQt and Qt packages for use with python3.6 only,

I have installed PyQt5 using sudo pip3.6 install pyqt5 , The instruction I was following says that Qt is included with PyQt5, Also in pyqt5 package in /usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/PyQt5 I see the Qt folder inside, But when I put qmake --version to check the qt version it gives me the following error:

```
qmake --version

bash: qmake: command not found...

Similar command is: 'make'
```

When using:

```
make --version
```

It gives the following:

```
GNU Make 3.82

Built for x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu

Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later

This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.

There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

using

```
rpm -ql qt
```

gives the following:

```
package qt is not installed
```

when I put sudo pip3.6 install qt5 to reinstall it, it gives me the following error " ```

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement qt5 (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for qt5"
```

When I use yum install qt5:

> ```
> Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks base
> | 3.6 kB 00:00 epel/x86_64/metalink
> | 24 kB 00:00 epel
> | 4.3 kB 00:00 extras
> | 3.4 kB 00:00 ius
> | 2.3 kB 00:00 updates
> | 3.4 kB 00:00 (1/3): ius/x86_64/primary_db
> | 206 kB 00:00 (2/3): epel/x86_64/updateinfo
> | 806 kB 00:01 (3/3): epel/x86_64/primary_db
> | 4.8 MB 00:08 Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile * base:
> ```
>
> mirror.sov.uk.goscomb.net * epel: ftp.heanet.ie * extras:
>   mirror.ox.ac.uk * ius: lon.mirror.rackspace.com * updates:
>   mirror.sov.uk.goscomb.net   No package qt5 available.   Error: Nothing
>   to do

Can someone please help. Thanks

Answer (score 13):

Find qt5 packages: `# yum search qt5` ... and search for qmake: `yum provides */bin/qmake*`

Install the CentOS 7 system qt5 :

```
# yum install qt5-qtbase-devel
```

... Provides /usr/bin/qmake-qt5

Comment: I want to install it on virtualenv - So do I activate the virtualenv and then pip3.6  install qt5-qtbase-devel-5.6.1-10.el7.x86_64 or how? I followed the steps above after activating the virtualenv and this is what I got:  qt5-qtbase-devel-5.6.1-3.el7.x86_64 : Development files for qt5-qtbase
Repo        : epel
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/lib64/qt5/bin/qmake
Filename    : /usr/lib64/qt5/bin/qmake-qt5
Filename    : /usr/bin/qmake-qt5